# Using an array populated in one function in another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I need to populate an array in one function and use this array in another function. However, this array returns an empty array when I check it in a different function.

Here's my sample code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3004;

let columns = new Array ();

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

//Server receives AJAX requests of JSON Data
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
// for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  updateworkbook(req.body); 
  res.send('Thanks for the data.');
});

//Here's where I'm using 'columns'
function updateworkbook(data) {
  getcolumns();
  console.log(columns);
  // some code to write back data to MYSQL which depends on 'COLUMNS'
}


//Here's where I'm populating 'columns' array
function getcolumns() {
  //Code to get a RowDataPacket object as 'results' from MySQL
  for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    columns.push(results[i]['COLUMN_NAME'])
  }
  console.log(columns)  //This works perfectly fine and prints out all the values
  return columns;
};
```

I expect to see all the column values that have been pushed during the getcolumns function, but it just prints out `[]`

Comment: `COLUMN_NAME` refers to some a child object inside each object of `results` array?

Comment: I have a feeling you're running into a timing issue: is `results` being populated asynchronously (e.g. via an AJAX request)? That might explain why logging `columns` returns an empty array. Can you show us what is invoking `getcolumns()`?

Comment: @Terry has the right answer in my opinion. Change `updateworkbook()` to be an asynchronous function, and make `console.log(columns);` wait for `getcolumns();` to finish.

Comment: @Terry, Edited the question to include almost the entire code. I'm listening for an ajax request through this and invoke getcolumns() for that. However, I'm not entirely clear as to how to make the updateworkbook function Async

Comment: I have updated my example with async code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to add that [using global vars is a bad practice](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/892.php) as it could lead to difficult to debug issues. Don't use them if you can.

Consider rewriting your code to this:

```
function getcolumns()
{
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
   {
       var columns = [];
       // populate the columns array asynchronously
       resolve(columns);
   });


}


function updateworkbook()
{
   getcolumns().then(function(cols){
      // do something with the value
      console.log(cols);
   });

}
```

Comment: I got it working a while back in the same way. Thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 0):

I assume `getcolumns()` has an AJAX request in it, which needs some time to finish. Additionally, try to stay away from using global variables.

Consider changing the flow of computations to asynchronous, resulting in (untested):

```
async function updateworkbook () {
  let result = await getcolumns();
  // Do something with result
};


function getcolumns() {
  let columns = [];
  // let results = someAjaxRequest;

  for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    columns.push(results[i]['COLUMN_NAME'])
  }

  return columns;
};
```

Comment: getcolumns() doesn't have any AJAX request, it uses a MYSQL connection pool. But getcolumns() in itself is invoked when an AJAX request is received. Updated the code in the question to give a better picture. Please have a look!

Answer (score -1):

It works fine in my case, here is the code:
[image]
Here is the Output:

[image]

There is nothing wrong in the code you have posted. you might be having the problem of timing [asynchronous operations as suggested in comments]